# sqlselect() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) lies

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I don't see the third argument. When I run this command:

```
used_emails = [row.email for row
    in db.execute(halo4.select([halo4.c.email],[halo4.c.email!='']))]
```

It says:

TypeError: select() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Where's the third argument?

Comment: It's `self` for class methods.

Answer (score 5):

Methods in Python accept *at least* the automatic argument `self`, so the method probably looks something like:

```
def select(self, someargument):
    # ...
```

Python takes care of the `self` argument, and then there is one more argument for you to pass in. When you pass in *two* arguments you end up with 3 total, and that's one too many.